# Only last object in an array got called, async.each or eachSeries does not work

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I am new in promises realm. I have implemented a find function where I have used the q promise library to get the document from Mongodb. Here is the code.

```
import { Collection } from "path"; // mongoose schema
import Q from "q";
const deferred = Q.defer();

const findOneDocument = (query) => {
   Collection.findOne(query, (err, res) => {
        if(err) {
            deferred.reject(err);
        }
        else {
            deferred.resolve(res);
        }
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}
```

It returns a q promise which get resolved when I get the data from database.

Now, I have to find multiple Collection documents on different query values like ["Value A", "Value B"].

But when I call the findOne on the every value of array using async.each or eachSeries. It only works for the last value "Value B". Code which I tried.

```
const promises = [];
async.each(array, (element, callback) => {
        // collecting the promise returned
        promises.push(findOne({"property": element}));
        callback();
    }, (err) => {
        if(err) {
            console.log("error has occured");
            console.dir(err);
        }
        else {
            console.log("all the values have been processed");
            Promise.all(promises).then((values) => {
                console.log("the promise of all values have been resolved");
                console.log("the value is :"+JSON.stringify(values));
            }, (err) => {
                console.dir(err);
            });
        }
    });
```

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thank You!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using one and the same `deferred` variable in all your calls to `findOne`, so once its promise is resolved, it will not start from scratch the next time you call `findOne`. All these `findOne` calls will in fact return the same single promise object.

So move that variable in the scope of `findOne`:

```
const findOneDocument = (query) => {
   const deferred = Q.defer();
   Collection.findOne(query, (err, res) => {
        if(err) {
            deferred.reject(err);
        }
        else {
            deferred.resolve(res);
        }
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}
```